# Fake content packages for website development

Tags: video, photos, lorem-ipsum

Does anyone know of any websites, or (preferably) downloadable packages that you can use as "real" data for websites that are database driven. Something like Lorem Ipsum, but on a much wider area (videos, photos, account details, etc...). My projects are getting to look a bit redundant since I'm using "asdfg", "qwerty" and generic wallpaper photos for everything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pics there's this: http://lorempixel.com/

That's all I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Thinkstock and just keep their logo in the photo to preserve the copyright.